# set value from NSString to a variable in html webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a html form with many input fields.
I want to set this field in `html` a `NSString` value in Objective C code.
I know we can set a value like this:

```
NSString *javascriptvalue;

NSString *javascript = @"document.getElementById('mytext').value = 'new value' ";
```

But how can I format and set the '`javascriptValue'` variable value to my `html element`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome NSString Catagory [here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m).

Use it like this 
`NSString *string = [@"YOUR HTML STRING" stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];`

Comment: I just need to set a value to my Html field. I dont need any parsing or formatting.I have this element in my HTML page                                                                    <input  id="key" class="key" name="key"/>